# how to multiprocessing a for loop with multi arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, parallel-processing, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a scrap code to crawl the information from a .aspx web page. I want to retrieve all the records in the database, but I don't have a list of the index of the records. I only know that the index is an integer between 1 and 9000000. Therefore, I'm thinking of using brute force for the index with a for loop.

I want to retrieve certain information from each record. So, I used beautifulsoup and pandas.DataFrame to store the info that I want. Then, I append the dataframe to gather the records.

for example:

```
df_all = pandas.DataFrame(col= ['A', 'B', 'C'])
# id: Unique id of each record; df_all: the dataframe that stores the records
def func(id, df_all):
    """
    Use beautifulsoup to collect the info from the webpage
    """
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], col= ['A', 'B', 'C'])
    df_all = df_all.append(df_temp, ignore_index= True)
    return df_all
```

I'm thinking of using several for loops to execute the func function at the same time. For example, the 1st client does 1 to 22500000; the second client does 22500001 to 4500000; and so forth. Then I can combine the results from each client. I tried to use ipyparallel, multiprocessing.pool, and joblib. But, it seemed that the structure of my function isn't correct for parallel processing. How should I modify my structure to perform a parallel for loop task? Or is there a better way to get the data from the database? There're just about 29k+ records in the database. To use the brute force for the index from 1 to 90000000 is really not the best way to approach this.

Comment: More detail please. Do you own the site, or is it someone else’s? If it’s someone else's, how are you connecting to their database? Why do you need an index? Where are you calling BeautifulSoup, and what objects does it return? What does a record look like? Is the goal storing records in a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: The easiest way to call the information of the record is using the corresponding id. I called the beautiful soup inside the function because each record has its own web page. The link is something like https://propaccess.trueautomation.com/clientdb/Property.aspx?prop_id=12345. But I have to get the cookie from the link: https://propaccess.trueautomation.com/clientdb/?cid=39 first. Then, I connect to each page by substituting the id number

Answer (score 0):

Okay kind of a dirty solution, but I think it works.

Have a dictionary mapping {`owner name` : `process_id`}

For each letter in the alphabet, have your program:

- run an 'owner name' search on the search page
- save all the `process_ids` in the dictionary
- go to the next page of results, repeat until all pages have been saved

For running the search and going to the next page, send an http POST. Open developer tools, click the button, see what your browser sends out, and then send the same thing from Python.

Then once you have all the `process_ids`, you can iterate through the dictionary and access each record page pretty easily.

Comment: I tried to use request.post. However, it seemed that the web page doesn't use form data to request the server. I looked up the html code and found that it's driven by some cookies. Could you shed some light on how to use request.post on this?